# Spring webClient getResponseBodyAsString() is empty(over spring 5.3.13)

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I'm using spring webClient for call some Rest API.

```
try {
  webClient.post().uri("apiUrl")
  .bodyValue(someParams)
  .retrive()
  .awaitBody<SomeResponseClass>()
} catch (ex: WebCleintResponseException) {
  ex.reponseBodyAsString
}
```

This is work right on under spring 5.3.12.
I can take response body in ex.

but over spring 5.3.13. is not work.
`resposeBody` is empty.

```
 webClient.post().uri("apiUrl")
  .bodyValue(someParams)
  .awaitExchange { response: ClientResponse ->
    if (response.satusCode().is2xxSuccessful) 
       response.awatieBody<SomeResponseClass>
    else if (response.statusCodes().isError)
       response.awatieBody<SomeResponseClass> 
    else throw response.createExceptionAndAwaite
}
```

This working one over spring 5.3.13.

So...What is different from this? I don't find anything on release note.
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/releases/tag/v5.3.13

I want to know what is changed.

Thanks guys.

Updated

I found this commit on github.
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/9197f15a306a497b3aa10c6ed48c581b3e938f58

Comment: What have you done to debug the issue? Have you compared the source code for `awaitBody` between the two versions?

Comment: Change to awaitExchange from awaitBody. I didn't compare source code yet.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar i found this commit log.  [DefaultClientResponse.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/9197f15a306a497b3aa10c6ed48c581b3e938f58#diff-ac6c81c3d2f30a7c326fae394cbaa5fbfe361221320d10c1839f352a851bcc3c)

Comment: @reperion Same problem here... How did you solve it???

Comment: @oilID change your code to second example.